# Pass internal variable as parameter in method

Tags: java, oop, methods

Say I have a class with multiple private String variables:

```
public class Children
{
    private String child0, child1;
}
```

I want to create a SetName method, which would set child0 or child1 to a specified value

So I could do something like this after instantiating Children class:

```
myChildren.SetName(child0, "Lucy");
```

How can I pass the private class variable String in a method? How do I code SetName method? I know I could create an array, and pass the element number, but that's not what I need, not how I want to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the children in one of `Map`'s implementation. `HashMap` is appropriate for most cases.

```
public class Children
{
    private Map<String, String> children = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void SetName(string child, string name)
    {
        children.put(child, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also add some input validation on `child` if you don't want to store values for any given string

Comment: Thanks! That will probably be something that will be most efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create Seperate Methods for each child.

```
public void setChild0Name(String name)
{
    this.child0 = name;
}
```

Comment: It's an idea, and I thought about doing it that way... but it will not work for what I need, unfortunately. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the private fields as they are:

```
private string child0, child1;
```

I'm not sure you can do anything else but implement one method for each string like RMT says.

On the other hand if that is not an issue then you can create a private `Dictionary<string, string>` and store child0, child1, etc. as keys with empty values.

Then your setter method would be:

```
myChildren.Set("child0","Lucy");
```

and you would just check if the "child0" key exists in your dictionary and update its value to "Lucy". If the given key doesnt exist you could throw an exception, add the new key value pair, etc.

Comment: `Dictionary` is a .NET BCL class. The tags say that the OP uses Java.